# Shopify access Denied for app installation

Tags: graphql

I'm trying to get all the installed apps of a shop using Shopify Graph QL just like this.

```
appInstallations(first: 10) {
  edges {
    node {
      id
    }
  }
}
```

And It gives me access denied. which access scope should I use?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it looks like although [it's documented](https://shopify.dev/api/admin-graphql/2022-04/queries/appinstallations) and there are no warnings about required scopes, it requires a scope that is no longer available to any apps other than the Shopify GraphiQL app:

- https://community.shopify.com/c/shopify-apis-and-sdks/access-scope-for-listing-appinstallations/m-p/866587
- https://community.shopify.com/c/shopify-apis-and-sdks/grapql-admin-api-issue-access-denied/td-p/456388